# Will `TypeDefinition for React v15.0` work with React v0.14.7

Tags: reactjs, typescript, npm, typescript-typings

In my existing project we are already using React v0.14.7.
Using npm I just did:

`npm install --save react@0.14.7 react-dom@0.14.7 @types/react @types/react-dom`

Then I checked `node_modules` folder and it has a `@types/react` folder which contains `index.d.ts` file. 
The first line of this file says:

`// Type definitions for React v15.0`

Now my question:

Is this compatible with React v0.14.7.
If not then what to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes you should be able to write code against those type definitions that will run with React 0.14.7.  According to the [changelog](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#1500-april-7-2016), there were no new APIs added in v15.0 that aren't in 0.14.7.